# Alignment issue with two tables in one cell on Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email

I am having an issue with an email template that has two tables aligned to left in one cell to make it responsive, but making it into a responsive isn’t the issue here.

When I opened up in Outlook 2010, the right column drops to the bottom and hangs in the right column. I noticed it only happens when the left column content is long.

Here is the HTML code:
Long left column: http://jsbin.com/aRUGOXu/1/edit?html,output
Short left column: http://jsbin.com/iGaFabo/1/edit?html,output

I read one of the article from Email on Acid and applied it, but still no luck. http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/removing_unwanted_spacing_or_gaps_between_tables_in_outlook_2007_2010 and applied it, but I ran into the same issue.

Here is the example that I did:
http://jsbin.com/eTAdOMe/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I would place each table inside it's own TD of the container table. You'll still be able to make it responsive by display:none; on the TDs of the container table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the Outlook page break issue. One of the wonderful MS word rendering quirks. You'll need to shorten your long column to avoid this issue. Here is some reference:

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010

Mailchimp also does a [good job of explaining the cause](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css) (although it is in their context)

[This article](http://mikethecoder.tumblr.com/post/861597102/outlook-2007-screws-up-spacing-where-page-breaks-would) suggests using `<tr style="page-break-before: always">`, although I've never tried that technique myself.